# Processing data while keeping frozen frontend database online

Tags: sql-server, snapshot

What is the best approach at having a "frontend" database online and working, while processing and generating new data in the back?

I have an scenario that some tables and even whole databases data needs to be manipulated and regenerated. After this processing is done, the new data is promoted to production (frontend). Once the processing is done, all the new data have to be available at once. So it can't be processed online.

I've come up with two different solutions, I'd like feedback on them since I'm not totally happy with either of them:

1. Work with snapshots while this processing is being performed. Once the processing is finished, re-create the snapshot with the current data and leave the real database ready to process again. This would have the downside of higher IO activity and fragmentation.
2. Work with an additional backend server and schema of backup-restore from one server to the other and then back. This would have the downside of network traffic, storage requirements, times and is more complex and prone to have issues. It would also require an additional server (thus, costs).

Environment: SQL Server 2014 Enterprise.

Additionally, I've been looking into Snapshot replication. But I'm not familiar with it. Given the data is not updated often (maybe once or twice a month) it looks like a potential solution as well.